# How to fix error 403 error php files

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and installed LAMP this way:

Install Apache

> sudo apt-get install apache2

Install MySQL

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Install PHP

> sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0

Restart Server

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Check Apache

> Working

Check PHP

> php -r 'echo "\n\nYour PHP installation is working fine.\n\n\n";'

Working

Files structure:

> /var/www/html/index.html > redirects to index.php
>   /var/www/html/pages/index.php < this file is not working and all php files

The owner group is set to:

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

The folders permissions are 755. The index.php permssions is 644 This is my apache2.conf file: https://ghostbin.com/paste/wwhog

But when i go to: http://localhost/pages/index.php I get this 403 Forbidden error. It seems like i can't see php files.

Comment: the apache conf link is not working

Comment: 0755 directories, 0644 files.. you got them round the wrong way. also apache user should own the files.. `www-data` not your user unless you have added it to www-data group. *fixing* permissions is the quickest way to break it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some ways how to fix it.

1. chmod files 644 and folders 755 (you have opposite side)
2. check owner of folders and files and chown them correctly.
3. Disable SELinux.

Checking error log file of Apache will give you more information about error.

Comment: I fixed issue 1 and 2. But i have no idea how to disable SELinux

Comment: @TristanMoorlag
1. Open file /etc/selinux/config
2. Change the line SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=permissive.
3. Reboot

Comment: Yes but it is empty somehow

Answer (score 0):

Try `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`, if you still get a 403, that means the problem is in apache2 conf, but i do not think.

I'll complete this response when i'll can see your apache's conf :) (apache2.conf & sites-enabled/000-default.conf -it should be the one you'are using in /var/www/html/-)